# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox - allmost there - only a little regex error left

Tags: regex, perl, firefox, firefox-addon, www-mechanize

Well to me Perl sometimes looks abit Abracadabra 
so many thanks for the patience with me...

**update;**  there were some errors untill user1269651 and Bodoin offered agreat fix

see the results of bodoins code..(note he has changed the code one time - i used here the first version ever...:;

```
linux-wyee:/home/martin/perl # perl test_7.pl
http://www.unifr.ch/sfm
http://www.zug.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.luzern.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch                                                                   http://www.phvs.ch                                                                         http://www.phtg.ch                                                                         http://www.phsg.ch                                                                         http://www.phsh.ch                                                                         Use of uninitialized value $png in print at test_7.pl line 25, <$urls> line 10.                                                                                        http://www.phr.ch                                                                          http://www.hepfr.ch/
http://www.phbern.ch
http://www.ph-solothurn.ch
http://www.pfh-gr.ch
Got status code 500 at test_7.pl line 14
linux-wyee:/home/martin/perl #
```

and the latest version of bodins code some results are looking like that..

```
Can't call method "addProgressListener" on an undefined value at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm line 566, <$urls> line 12.
```

well some minor things left - see above... what can we  do with those little errors..
btw: what about the idea of **storing the results in a folder.**.. /(called images or so!?)

**end of update...**

here the **inital thread** starts - and gives an outline of what is wanted:

i need to have some thumbnails from websites but i tried to use wget - but that does not work for me, since i need some rendering functions what is needet: i have a list of 2,500 URLs, one on each line, saved in a file. Then i  want a script - see it below - to open the file, read a line, then retrieve the website and save  the image as a small thumbnail.

well since i have a bunch of web-sites (2500) i have to make up my mind about the naming of the results.

```
http://www.unifr.ch/sfm
http://www.zug.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.luzern.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.phvs.ch
http://www.phtg.ch
http://www.phsg.ch
http://www.phsh.ch
http://www.phr.ch
http://www.hepfr.ch/
http://www.phbern.ch
```

So far so good, well i think i try something like this

We also have to close a filehandler if we do not need it anymore. Besides this we can use 'or die' on open. i did it - see below!

Btw we need a good file name. Since i have a huge list of urls then i get a huge list of output files. Therefore i need to have good file names. Can we reflect those things and needs in the programme!?

the script does not start at all ....

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize::Firefox();

open(INPUT, "<urls.txt") or die $!;

while (<INPUT>) {
        chomp;
        next if $_ =~ m/http/i;
        print "$_\n";
        $mech->get($_);
        my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
        my $name = "$_";
        $name =~s#http://##is;
        $name =~s#/##gis;$name =~s#\s+\z##is;$name =~s#\A\s+##is;
        $name =~s/^www\.//;
        $name .= ".png";
        open(my $out, ">",$name) or die $!;
        binmode($out);
        print $out $png;
        close($out);
        sleep (5);
}
```

Comment: btw, it's a "file handle" (something that allows one to hold a file), not a "filehandler" (something that acts in response to files).

Comment: What's your question? You imply you are getting incorrect results, yet you don't specify what those results are and what they should be instead.

Comment: hi ikegami  - many thanks for the quick  reply - i get no results at all - i want to have little thumbnails - saved locally and named like the urls.... doable

Comment: update; there seem to be some errors with mechanize.... i guess so!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
while (my $name = <DATA>) {
        chomp ($name) ;

        #$mech->get($_);
        #my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
        $name =~ s#http://##;  #REMOVE THIS LINE

        $name =~s#/#-#gis;
        $name =~s#\s+\z##is;$name =~s#\A\s+##is;

        $name =~s/^www\.//;

        $name .= ".png";

        print $name . "\n\n";   #REMOVE THIS LINE       
        #open(my $out, ">",$name) or die $!;
        #binmode($out);
        #print $out $png;
        #close($out);
        #sleep (5);
}


__DATA__
http://www.unifr.ch/sfm
http://www.zug.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.luzern.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.phvs.ch
http://www.phtg.ch
http://www.phsg.ch
http://www.phsh.ch
http://www.phr.ch
http://www.hepfr.ch/
http://www.phbern.ch
```

You should be able to modify it for your needs, I commented out all but the regex stuff. I also changed one regec to replace a '/' with a '-' so that there is less probability of falsly generating duplicate URL's.

So that  `http://www.unifr.ch/sfm` will look like this: `unifr.ch-sfm`

Hope this helps

Comment: hello dear  user 1269651 . thx alot - looks impressive!! what about the idea of **storing the results in a folder** called images or so!?) is this doable? it would help alot since i get stored the results in a folder. And the many results do not mess the machine... look forward to hear from you - many many thanks in advande!!

Comment: You can store in a directory thusly: open(my $out, '>', "path/$name") or die $!;

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code. Most significant is the line

```
next if $_ =~ m/http/i;
```

which discards all lines from `urls.txt` that contain `http`, which isn't what you want.

Rather than go through each problem indicvidually I am offering a functional version. I hope this is satisfactory.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize::Firefox();

open my $urls, '<', 'urls.txt' or die $!;

while (<$urls>) {
  chomp;
  next unless /^http/i;
  print "$_\n";
  $mech->get($_);
  my $png = $mech->content_as_png;
  my $name = $_;
  $name =~ s#^http://##i;
  $name =~ s#/##g;
  $name =~ s/\s+\z//;
  $name =~ s/\A\s+//;
  $name =~ s/^www\.//;
  $name .= ".png";
  open my $out, ">", $name or die $!;
  binmode $out;
  print $out $png;
  close $out;
  sleep 5;
}
```

Comment: hello deaar Borodin - many many thanks - i try it out. You guy rock!!

Comment: well some minor things left - see above... what can we  do with those little errors.. see in the initial posting...
btw: what about the idea of **storing the results in a folder.**.. /(called images or so!?)